# TypeScript/Redux. Cannot write interface for Reducer. Error TS2322

Tags: typescript, redux

I cannot understand, why I always gets an error once use the `interface ITitleIconSwitch` with declarated type for `state` in it.

```
interface ITitleIconSwitch {
  'TITLE_ICON_SWITCH': (state: object) => {
    state: object; // this line provides me with an error stack. But! Without 'state' interface works fine. Why?
    titleSwitch: boolean;
  }
}

const actionHandlers: ITitleIconSwitch = {
  'TITLE_ICON_SWITCH': state => ({
    ...state,
    titleSwitch: false
  })
}
```

The error message:

> TS2322:
>
> Type '{ [TITLE_ICON_SWITCH]: (state: object) => { titleSwitch: false; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IActionHandlers'.
>
> Type '{ [TITLE_ICON_SWITCH]: (state: object) => { titleSwitch: false;
>   }; }' is not assignable to type 'IStateUpdate'.
>
> Property ''STATE_UPDATE'' is missing in type '{ [TITLE_ICON_SWITCH]: (state: object) => { titleSwitch: false; }; }'.

Comment: What are the definitions of `IActionHandlers` and `TITLE_ICON_SWITCH`?  Please provide a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen oh, sorry. I had a type in make post. Please, read it one more time.

Comment: As the error message says, the object you are returning from the function does not have the `state` property declared by the line you marked in the interface.  The returned object includes `...state`, which adds all the properties of the `state` argument to the returned object; this is different from adding a single property named `state` that contains the `state` argument.  What were you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your types for reducer as function, not like object, because you declare you reducer in like object-oriented style. So you need to do the same with types for this reducer:

```
export interface ITitleIconSwitch { . // typing for reducer
  [TITLE_ICON_SWITCH]: (state: object) => {
    titleSwitch: boolean
  }
}

export interface ITitleState { // typing for reducer state
  titleSwitch: boolean
}
```

and then add them to the particular reducer:

```
const actionHandlers: IActionHandlers = {
  [TITLE_ICON_SWITCH]: (state: ITitleState) => ({
    ...state,
    titleSwitch: false
  })
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is great and easy. Thanks!